# weird behavior of recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to have a layout as shown in snapshot

**green** is to_message_item.xml layout and **white** is from_message_item.xml layout

[image: desired behavior]

My Message.class is

```
public class Message {
    private String message;
    private String sentAt;
    private boolean isSend;

    public Message(String message, String sentAt, boolean isSend){
        this.message = message;
        this.sentAt = sentAt;
        this.isSend = isSend;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getSentAt() {
        return sentAt;
    }
    public boolean getSend() {
        return isSend;
    }
}
```

MessageHolder.class is

```
public class MessageHolder extends ViewHolder {

    public ImageView mToImageView;
    public TextView mToMessageTextView, mToSentAtTextView;

    public MessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mToImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar_iv);
        mToMessageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_tv);
        mToSentAtTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sent_at_tv);
    }
}
```

MessageAdapter.class is

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private List<Message> mMessageList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<Message> mMessageList){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mMessageList = mMessageList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView;
        Message data = mMessageList.get(viewType);
        Log.e("MESSAGE", " Booleans are " + data.getSend());
        if (data.getSend()) {
            rootView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.to_message_item, null);
        } else {
            rootView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.from_message_item, null);
        }

        return new MessageHolder(rootView);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MessageHolder messageHolder = (MessageHolder) holder;
        messageHolder.mToImageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_choose_image));
        messageHolder.mToMessageTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
        messageHolder.mToSentAtTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getSentAt());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMessageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_rv);
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MainActivity.this, dummyMessages());
        mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
    }

private List<Message> dummyMessages(){

        Message message1 = new Message("A", "B", true);
        Message message2 = new Message("A", "B", false);
        Message message3 = new Message("A", "B", true);
        Message message4 = new Message("A", "B", false);
        Message message5 = new Message("A", "B", true);
        Message message6 = new Message("A", "B", false);
        Message message7 = new Message("A", "B", true);
        Message message8 = new Message("A", "B", false);

        mMessageList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        mMessageList.add(message1);
        mMessageList.add(message2);
        mMessageList.add(message3);
        mMessageList.add(message4);
        mMessageList.add(message5);
        mMessageList.add(message6);
        mMessageList.add(message7);
        mMessageList.add(message8);

        return mMessageList;
    }
```

Using the code above gives me output as

[image: weird behavior]

## UPDATE

changes made in Adapter class

```
 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView;
        Message data = mMessageList.get(viewType);
        Log.e("MESSAGE", " Booleans are " + data.getSend());
        if (data.getSend()) {
            rootView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.to_message_item, null);
        } else {
            rootView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.from_message_item, null);
        }
        return new MessageHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mMessageList.get(position).getSend()){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MessageHolder messageHolder = (MessageHolder) holder;
        messageHolder.mToImageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_choose_image));
        messageHolder.mToMessageTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
        messageHolder.mToSentAtTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getSentAt());
    }
```

Comment: override `RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemViewType(int position)`

Comment: how? any example please!!

Comment: you dont know how to override some methods?

Comment: Ooops! Sorry I didn't mean that, but I mean to ask that what functionality should I add in that method or only I should override that method??

Comment: I just overridden the method and got the same result as before.

Comment: how many **different** view types do you have?

Comment: two view types are there, one for sent and one for  received messages.

Comment: so return two different integers from `getItemViewType`

Comment: and now that "view type" will be passed to `onCreateViewHolder` method where you can use it when inflating the layouts

Comment: it created a new issue that is if I add first Item as  `new Message("A", "B", true);` to _mMessageList_ I get both views (e.g sent and received), but if I add first item as `new Message("A", "B", false);` I get only one view, what is wrong with my code please!

Comment: what both view? if you have only **one** `Message` in your `dummyMessages`: `Message("A", "B", true);` then you can see two views?

Comment: are you sure that `data.getSend()` in your ViewHolder returns the correct values?

Comment: no but if I add more than one as first `new Message("A", "B", true);` and second `new Message("A", "B", false);` I get both but if I add `new Message("A", "B", false);` and second `new Message("A", "B", true);` Iget only one repeatedly

Comment: I add more than one as first `new Message("A", "B", true);` and second `new Message("A", "B", false);` I get correct values but if  I add `new Message("A", "B", false);` and second `new Message("A", "B", true);` I get incorrect valuses

Comment: post your modified `getItemViewType` `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` methods

Comment: See my __UPDATE__

Comment: in `onCreateViewHolder` see the second parameter

Comment: Yes that is __int viewType__

Comment: so why do you call `Message data = mMessageList.get(viewType);` ?

Comment: Sorry but how could I differentiate between tow layouts and inflate them

Comment: how? using the `int viewType`, btw you dont have to return 0 or 1 from `getItemViewType` - just return `R.layout.from_message_item` or `R.layout.to_message_item`

Comment: thank you very much that was very bad of me, that's why at the beginning I asked you 
__how? any example please!!__

Comment: I have solved my this problem, again thanks for your time...